# JsonParser get 1st of the duplicate keys

Tags: java, json, duplicates

I've created a custom JsonDeserializer and it works great - except for one thing.

Whenever I try a json with duplicate keys, it gets the last instance.
Our requirement is to get the first instance, no errors needed.

I'm using JsonParser (class is extended to JsonDeserializer and overrides deserialize) to get the treenode and manually do business logic from there.

```
{
  "key1":"val1", -> I only need this, discard the rest of same key
  "key1":"val2", -> It's showing this
  "key2":"val3"
}
```

Any ideas what I need to do to get the first one instead of last?

```
@JsonComponent
public class CustomJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<TestDTO> {

@Override
public TestDTO deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    Boolean isField1Missing = false;
    Boolean isField2Missing = false;
    Boolean isField3Missing = false;
    Boolean isField4Missing = false;
    Boolean isField5Missing = false;
    String field1 = null;
    String field2 = null;
    String field3 = null;
    Integer field5 = null;

    JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);

    if (jsonNode.path("field1").isMissingNode()) {
        System.out.println("Missing field1");
        isField1Missing = true;
    } else {
        field1 = determineStringValue(jsonNode, "field1");
    }
    
    if (jsonNode.path("field2").isMissingNode()) {
        System.out.println("Missing field2");
        isField2Missing = true;
    } else {
        field2 = determineStringValue(jsonNode, "field2");
    }
    
    if (jsonNode.path("field3").isMissingNode()) {
        System.out.println("Missing field3");
        isField2Missing = true;
    } else {
        field3 = determineStringValue(jsonNode, "field3");
    }
    
    if (jsonNode.path("field5").isMissingNode()) {
        System.out.println("Missing field5");
        isField5Missing = true;
    } else {
        field5 = determineIntegerValue(jsonNode, "field5");
    }
    
    return new TestDTO(field1, field2, field3, field5, null, isField1Missing, isField2Missing, isField3Missing, isField4Missing, isField5Missing );
}

private String determineStringValue(JsonNode jsonNode, String field) {
    
    String returnStr = null;
    
    if (jsonNode.path(field).isNull()) {
        System.out.println("null field " + field);
        return null;
    }
    
    if (!Objects.isNull(jsonNode.path(field).asText())) {
        returnStr =  jsonNode.path(field).asText();
        System.out.println("value " + field + " " + returnStr);
    }
    
    return returnStr;
}

private Integer determineIntegerValue(JsonNode jsonNode, String field) throws JsonMappingException {
    
    String returnStr = null;
    Integer returnInt = null;
    
    if (jsonNode.path(field).isNull()) {
        System.out.println("null field " + field);
        return null;
    }
    
    if (!Objects.isNull(jsonNode.path(field).asText())) {
        returnStr =  jsonNode.path(field).asText();
        System.out.println("value " + field + " " + returnStr);
    }
    
    try {
        returnInt = Integer.parseInt(returnStr);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
//          returnInt = -999;
        throw new JsonMappingException("Not readable Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from String \"" + returnStr + "\": not a valid Integer value");
    }
    
    System.out.println(returnInt);
    return returnInt;
}
}
```

Comment: Objects with duplicate keys are not guaranteed [by the JSON spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc8259.txt) to be handled in any specific way: "When the names within an object are not
 unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is
 unpredictable. " In other words: depending on any specific behaviour for this kinds of objects is not JSON-conformant and should be avoided, if interoperability is a goal!

Comment: I understand, but I need to handle them in a very specific way. :)

Comment: Unfortunately the configuration of the Json parser is "implementation specific", so I don't know which implementation you end up using and if it can be configured to handle it in a specific way. **If** there is such a configuration then [`Json.createParserFactory(Map<String,?>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/Json.html#createParserFactory-java.util.Map-) is how you specify it.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it: if you used the `JsonParser` API itself, then it *could* report all three keys. In other words: Don't build a JsonNode and analyze that, but get the event stream and check what this says. There you can probably just look at the events and ignore all but the first of each name.

Comment: ^ [here's a guide to using the streaming parser](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api#parsing-json)

Comment: How can I flag you both as answer? The only issue I have right now is when I close the JsonParser, I get na error lol (The objects this was meant to use was on a list on the request). Any ideas what will happen if I don't close?